# ReferenceError: MouseEvent is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, typescript2.0, angular2-universal

I am trying to use [ng2-select](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select) in a project which uses [angular/universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) (TypeScript 2.x) as backbone.

(I tried to add ng2-select in an angular-cli generated project, it works well though)

Just after adding these two lines:

```
import { SELECT_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-select/ng2-select';

@Component({
  directives: [SELECT_DIRECTIVES],
  ...
```

I already got the error in my terminal:

> ```
> ReferenceError: MouseEvent is not defined
>     at /my-project/node_modules/ng2-select/components/select/off-click.js:33:42
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/my-project/node_modules/ng2-select/components/select/off-click.js:43:2)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
>     at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/my-project/node_modules/ng2-select/components/select/select.js:20:19)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
>     at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/my-project/node_modules/ng2-select/components/select.js:2:16)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
> ```

This is my **tsconfig.json** file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"]
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "!node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select/issues/258.

Please track this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the error was caused because the directive didn't load properly.

1) Make sure the right Components are being imported, and verify if `MouseEvent` is defined

2) Verify if all the components are being exported;

3) In

```
@Component({
  directives: [SELECT_DIRECTIVES],
  ...
```

make sure `SELECT_DIRECTIVES` isn't an array object. If it is, i think you should try using

`[ ...SELECT_DIRECTIVES ]`

Comment: thanks, but still same error. Note that `MouseEvent` is inside of the **node_modules** folder. And it works well in my angular-cli generated project. I guess it somehow related with **tsconfig.json**